# DS18B20 sending variable via Enthernet shield

Tags: arduino-uno, data-type, ds18b20, convert

I am trying to send temperature read from DS18B20 to a web server. I know two things: to read a temperature, and to send something to web server. What I don't know is how to convert float that temperature reading function is giving to me to string that I need to send to the server.

I am reading temperature with OneWire and DallasTemperature libraries (just a standard sketch ending with:

```
sensors.requestTemperatures();
Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));//sensors.getTempCBy... returns float, from my understanding
```

I am sending data via ethernet shield, and important part is:

```
 client.println("GET /led-ekran-vremenska-prognoza/?temp1=" + String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)) + "&temp2=" + String(dht.readTemperature()) + "&humidity="+String(dht.readHumidity())+"&secret=111 HTTP/1.1");
```

I know that the problem is that String(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)) is not converting to right value. Arduino just stops working there, if that makes sense. At least serial communication stops working, since I don't see any more output...

Basically, TL:DR, I think that the question is how to convert float to string in Arduino? I have read a million topics on this but still cant figure it out, especially sicne it works for temp2 and humidity in example above.

Comment: `I think that the question is how to convert float to string in Arduino?` ... why the misleading title? ... why all the stuff about 1-wire and temperature?  .... ask what you mean to ask, do not give a long unrelated story

Comment: Uhm, maybe because "I think" part? I am not so good with Arduino programming, and I don't see how including as much RELEVANT information as possible is a bad thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Having re-read the question just before posting this answer, I find it odd that the DHT temp and humidity (also floats) work for you - how odd

Use `dtostrf`

```
char tStr[9] = { 0 }; // buffer to store the string - length 9, because at most you need 8 chars "-23.5678" , plus null terminator
dtostrf(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0), 7, 3, tStr)
```

Note: `dtostrf` returns char pointer to `tStr`

The 7, 3 is ... 7 = total length of string, 3 = number of decimal digits - So depending on your resolution, you can change those values

```
Resolution     Arguments to dtostrf
 9             5, 1                  -nn.n
10             6, 2                  -nn.nn
11             7, 3                  -nn.nnn
12             8, 4                  -nn.nnnn
```

Of course, you can use any arguments for any resolution, the table just shows what you would need if you wanted to show the exact data coming in

For example, I use resolution 12, but I'm not really interested in displaying more than tenths of a degree - so I use `5,1` for the format

Comment: This is an awesome explanation of dtostrf. I experimented a little with samples that I found online, but could not figure it out.
Anyway, I tried the code that you posted, and I get the error when I try to combine results with the rest of the string:
`client.println("GET /led-ekran-vremenska-prognoza/?temp1=" + tStr + "&temp2=" + String(dht.readTemperature()) + "&humidity="+String(dht.readHumidity())+"&secret= HTTP/1.1");`
Error:
`invalid operands of types 'const char [42]' and 'char [9]' to binary 'operator+'`

Comment: the issue is the `+` operator on `char *` .. try `+ String(tStr) +` ...